# Chromecast has created its own unsecured wifi network, is this ok ?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, chromecast

We have an Chromecast Ultra (4k) on our network.

Ive noticed that its created its own unsecured wifi network, presumably so you can get guests / visitors to connect to the chromecast wifi, rather than giving them full network access or having to setup a guest network.

Is the Chromecast wifi network secure, eg. could anyone hop from it to our main network ?

Can / should the Chromecast wifi network be disabled ?

Comment: That network is supposed to give access to the configuration. From there I think you're supposed to set it to connect to your own network. In summary, it's a temporary network for setting up the device only.

Comment: @MichaelBay ah ok, we just had a power cut which made everything reboot which is probably why its the first time ive noticed it. Perhaps its wiped its config some how. We connect the chromecast using the ethernet LAN adaptor. In that case dose it even need to be configured ?

Comment: The reuired configuration is for connecting it to your own WiFi network. It should work as is when using Ethernet but you can also access the settings and try to disable the ad-hoc network if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to setup Chromecast connecting a laptop to Chromecast's own Wi-Fi? (i.e. without the use of a smartphone or tablet)